# How to make a white with 85% opacity?

Tags: flutter

The highest opasity defined for white swatch is

```
static const Color white70 = Color(0xB3FFFFFF);
```

To make a white with a higher opasity, say 85%, should I create a custom `Color` variable in my code or it's somehow available in Flutter sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are serveral ways to achieve this.

1. `Color(0xB3FFFFFF).withAlpha(217);` (where 0 is fully opaque and 255 is completly visible)
2. `Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85)`
3. you could directly edit the hex color. If you take for example `0xB3FFFFFF` the first to signs after the `x` represent the opacity.

The most convinient way probably is to use `.withOpacity(0.85)` save it as a `const` and reuse it where you need it.